# Cron job - every minute between 8:30 and 9:00

Tags: cron

I want to run a script 8:30 to 4 each day.
Currently I have this to handle the 9 to 4.

```
*/1 9-15 ? * MON-FRI *
```

I think I discovered that the 15 is inclusive, so this will run up to 15:59

Can some confirm if the following will handle 8:30 to 9?

```
30-59/1 8 ? * MON-FRI *
```

And then to run the script one last time at sometime between 4pm and 4:01pm

```
* 16 ? * MON-FRI *
```

Comment: You can test various combinations at [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)